# scss for loop is not cascading correctly

Tags: css, sass

I have this for loop created like this:

```
.hero {
  @for $i from 1 through 100 {
    &.aspect-ratio--#{$i} {
      @include aspect-ratio(16, $i);
    }

    &.aspect-ratio-sm--#{$i} {
      @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
        @include aspect-ratio(16, $i);
      }
    }

    &.aspect-ratio-md--#{$i} {
      @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
        @include aspect-ratio(16, $i);
      }
    }

    &.aspect-ratio-lg--#{$i} {
      @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
        @include aspect-ratio(16, $i);
      }
    }

    &.aspect-ratio-xl--#{$i} {
      @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) {
        @include aspect-ratio(16, $i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I create an element, like this:

```
<div class="hero aspect-ratio-md--6 aspect-ratio-sm--8 aspect-ratio--10"></div>
```

it's not respecting the order I declared my classes, so when I am in a **md** and above, instead of using aspect-ratio-md-6 it's actually using the aspect-ratio-10 instead.
like this:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it voted down, but I figured this out.
It's because of how my loop was working, it was getting to 8 after 6, so that took precedence.
I changed my loop to this:

```
$breakpoints: sm, md, lg, xl, xxl;

.hero {
  @each $breakpoint in $breakpoints {
    @for $i from 1 through 100 {
      &.aspect-ratio-#{$breakpoint}-#{$i} {
        @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint) {
          @include aspect-ratio(16, $i);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this worked. Why? Because it looks through the breakpoints first meaning the last breakpoint will always take precedence over the first, then it loops from 1 to 100 and creates the classes, again, the later numbers taking precedence over the earlier numbers (not needed, but good to know)